# File can't be found in MSI after editing a different file

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I am writing a utility in c# to edit a file in my MSI (the CAB is embedded). My approach is to open the database, execute my view, save the stream to a cab file, unpack the file, edit the file I want, save, repack and then save the stream back to the database.

The file that is not installing is sequence 17, so I'm assuming the first 16 are working fine. I haven't altered it in anyway and I receive the standard "The file ... cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file cab1.cab"

The original MSI is created with WiX.
Here is part of the log where it fails:

```
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:02:963]: File: C:\ProductDir\File1.exe;  To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:02:963]: Source for file 'File1' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: File1.exe,  Directory: C:\ProductDir\,  Size: 38538352
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:03:205]: Executing op: FileCopy(SourceName=d-c9wzx6.dll|FailingFile.dll,SourceCabKey=FailingFile,DestName=FailingFile.dll,Attributes=512,FileSize=1286768,PerTick=65536,,VerifyMedia=1,,,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=2.6.0.4,Language=1033,InstallMode=58982400,,,,,,,)
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:03:205]: File: C:\ProductDir\FailingFile.dll;    To be installed;    Won't patch;    No existing file
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:03:205]: Source for file 'FailingFile' is compressed
InstallFiles: File: FailingFile.dll,  Directory: C:\ProductDir\,  Size: 1286768
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:03:206]: Note: 1: 1334 2: FailingFile 3: cab1.cab 
Error 1334. The file 'FailingFile' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'cab1.cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.
MSI (s) (88:54) [08:51:04:317]: Product: MyProduct V2.2.0 -- Error 1334. The file 'FailingFile' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'cab1.cab'. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.
```

Comment: can you show your Wix file code here please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's an installer log tell you?  Have you updated the FileSize column in the File table?  Have you run MSI validation after editing the MSI.

My instinct is you've created a malformed MSI but I need more information to be more specific in how to fix it.

Comment: I've added part of the logs to my original post. Orca validation doesn't reveal any issues.

The file size of the failing file hasn't changed and the first 16 (including the changed file) work.

Comment: Let me make a suggestion.  Instead of tampering with the original CAB just supersede the original file.  I've written code in the past that does it and it works well.  You'll have to create a new cab and update the Media table along with the File table (sequence #s).  Send me an email at chrpai@iswix.com and I can share some starter code with you.